# iOs 5 SDK UIGestureRecognizer: Differ between multiple imageViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, sdk, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I try to differ between multiple imageViews, that you can create with an IBAction.

here's my code for the action:

```
-(IBAction) addObject:(id)sender {

    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Stuhl.png"];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 40.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    Bild *newImageView = [[Bild alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [newImageView setImage:image];
    newImageView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    [theView addSubview:newImageView];
    [arryData addObject:newImageView];

}
```

And then my problem: How can I differ between the imageView, when I clicked on the button with the IBAction addObject multiple times?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer   shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer     *)otherGestureRecognizer
{       

if (gestureRecognizer.view != imageView /*<---Here's my problem*/)
    return NO;

if (gestureRecognizer.view != otherGestureRecognizer.view)
    return NO;

if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] ||     [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
    return NO;
}
```

I hope for help,
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I solved it by myself, but thanks for the answer. I just searched for the wrong method.

```
-(IBAction) addObject:(id)sender {

    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Stuhl.png"];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 40.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    Bild *newImageView = [[Bild alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [newImageView setImage:image];
    newImageView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    [theView addSubview:newImageView];
    /*--->*/[self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:newImageView];/*<---*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to compare object, you shouldn't use == or !=

use

```
if(![gestureRecognizer.view isEqual:imageView])
    return NO;

if (![gestureRecognizer.view isEqual:otherGestureRecognizer.view])
    return NO;
```

Comment: thanks, but thats not my problem, the code, I used for the gesturerecognizer is copied from apples sample code. My problem is that, when I tap the add button multiple times, there are multiple images all named "imageView". In the gestureRecognizers method, I have to tell it, how the imageView is called, that I want to move, but if there are more of it, I don't know how to let the program give the imageviews seperate names to differ between them.

Comment: you can set the tag, for example, UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init]; then imageView.tag = 100; after that, on the gestureRecognizer, check its view's tag, gestureRecognizer.view.tag, you can compare the tag.